# Build failed with error Error code 72 for command: xcrun

Tags: ios, cordova

I am porting an phone app project into VS2017 and get the below error when I try to build for a Remote Device.  This code has built correctly on VS2015 and runs fine in an Android simulator.  Just get this error on and IOS remote device, which I need to run to create an .ipa file.  I see a bunch of posts on an error 65, but none on error 72 that I can find.  Can you help me on how to fix this?  Thanks.

"

Severity Code
Description Project
File Line
Suppression State
Error Remote build error from the build server http://10.13.4.29:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Error code 72 for command: xcrun with args: -sdk,iphoneos,PackageApplication,-v,/Users/administrator/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/8936/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/OnticMobile.app,-o,/Users/administrator/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/8936/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going back to XCode version 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you use ionic build ios --device … it’s the device flag that needs the packageApplication, but which is not available in 8.3

I got around the problem without downgrading XCode, as follows:

- Load your project into XCode 8.3 by clicking your .xcodeproj file (in
  platforms/ios/build) and choose Product > Archive.
- Select the archive in the next screen and click ‘Export’ button. Choose ‘Save for Ad Hoc
- Deployment’ and you’ll get an .IPA file, just as if you had used ionic build ios --device.